Бот автокликер с трекингом объектов на Python
хочу сделать автокликер для компьютера для игры Blum (телеграм мини приложение) на питоне. Суть заключается в том, что сверху экрана падают зелёные снежинки и на них нужно кликнуть чтоб заработать очки, но среди них также попадаются бомбочки, которые снимают все очки, поэтому обычный автокликер не подходит. Я хочу написать автокликер который бы в реальном времени распознавал и отслеживал снежинки и кликал на них. Подскажите, какие библиотеки понадобятся и как отслеживать именно движение объектов с экрана пк.
Я так понимаю нужен будет Open CV?
Также думал мб писать его под андроид, но понял что на пк это легче будет, нет опыта написания под андроид.


Ставите OpenCV, следом PyAutoGUI -> читаете документацию PyAutoGUI -> пишите код ‍♀️

Как более быструю, в плане работоспособности, альтернативу PyAutoGUI могу предложить Pynput

Захват экрана: Использовать библиотеку pyautogui для захвата экрана.Распознавание объектов: Использовать OpenCV для распознавания снежинок и бомбочек.Автокликер: Использовать pyautogui для автоматического клика по координатам найденных снежинок, избегая бомбочек.

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
